# Reducing size of apk through libraries

Tags: android, apk, libraries, android-library

I want to decrease the size of apk.I have already used Lint and Proguard to remove unused resources and reduce size.Now i am looking at libraries like ButterKnife which can reduce the lines of code.Are their any other good libraries which can help in minimizing lines of code and hence help in reducing size of apk?

Comment: This would be helpful if you included what libraries you use: perhaps there are smaller alternatives.

Comment: ButterKnife will not reduce the number of lines of code (in the apk). While it means you write less code the code generation most likely ends up being more code total compiled.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge list of libraries available which can reduce the line of codes for common operations you perform in Android:

1. Retrofit 1.9.0 : for REST API calls
2. Event Bus 2.4.0 : to get rid of interfaces
3. Butterknife 6.1.0 : for UI annotations
4. Lombok : for getter setter
5. Gson2.2.4 : JSON parsing
6. EventBus : for event handling

and many more.

http://retrofiteventbus.blogspot.in/2015/02/this-is-what-they-sayeventbus-less-code.html